# Component is rendering even if deleted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Super weird behaviour when rendering my react component.

Component Herolist is rendering  , even if i delete it completly!

**The main problem is that i want other divs/ components rendered after Herolist, but they keep getting ignored!**

I have tried cleaning browser cookies and edge. I have tried a new "npm start".
I get this warning in node:

```
./src/js/components/Pagecontent.js
  Line 4:   'Pagecontent' is defined but never used                                 no-unused-vars
  Line 13:  Comments inside children section of tag should be placed inside braces  react/jsx-no-comment-textnodes

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

Pagecontent.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Herolist from './Herolist';

class Pagecontent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <div id ="pageContent" className="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix row">

  /*Still renders if i delete this completly       
   *<Herolist />  
   */ 

        <div id="heroToBeDisplayed" className="ui-widget-content ui-state-default col-lg-5 col-md-push-5">
          <h4 className="ui-widget-header">Your Hero</h4>
        </div> 
        <div id="trash" className="ui-widget-content ui-state-default col-lg-2">
          <h4 className="ui-widget-header">Enemies</h4>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
   }
 }
 export default Herolist;
```

Herolist.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Hero from './Hero';

class Herolist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      heroes: [],
    };
  }

getReports() {
    fetch('http://xxxx/getHeroes', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        }
    })
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(result => {
            this.setState({
                heroes: result})
        });
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.getReports();
}


  render() {
     return (
     <ul id="heroList" className="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix col-lg-3 col-md-pull-5">
        <h4 className="ui-widget-header">Heroes</h4>
        <div className="row">
            {this.state.heroes.map(hero =>(
            <Hero hero={hero} /> 
         ))}
            </div>
        </ul>
    );
  }
}
export default Herolist;
```

Expected behaviour:

[image: Expected]

Actual behaviour:

[image: Actual]

Comment: The first warning is because you are not exporting the PageContent component inside the Pagecontent.js file. The second warning is because you must place comments inside braces. Probably the error is because you are importing the PageContent and rendering it in another file, but as you do not export anything in the PageContent.js file you are rendering undefined in the end.

Comment: You managed to spot the error in Pagecontent.js: export default Herolist; Ofcourse this should be export default Pagecontent;...I knew it was something this stupid. Thanks alot

Comment: No problem. I'm here to help :)